# Windows Server 2008 R2 firewall order of rules

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, rules

I would like to have one rule that allows Internet Explorer to connect to my proxy-server, but block all other applications to connect to the proxy-server.

Is that possible?

I've tried one rule that opens "Internet-Explorer" -> "Proxy" and a second rule that blocks any "any application" -> "Proxy" but that is not working because deny-rules are higher prioritized than allow-rules.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box. Simple like that. You can filter in the proxy based on browser identification string - and hope noone fakes that.